# Why is Daniel specifically referred to as a beloved man?

Tags: names, daniel-book-of, daniel-the-person

In Daniel 10:11, 19 Daniel is referred to as a beloved man. Commentators explain this term to mean pure, or that his actions were beloved. Midrashim explain this more generally that the righteous are beloved to God, angels and man.

Daniel certainly exhibited many righteous traits, but so did many other people. Furthermore the title beloved man seems to be unique. Why is this term used specifically and why is it applied to Daniel exclusively?

Comment: Everybody loves a "Daniel", but, aaaah, I'm a bit conceited, today :-) :-) I think he is given this title because despite one of the most tortuous activities (Yosef was imprisoned - closest, perhaps, known imprisonment to Daniel's. But Daniel was fed to the lions) he survived, held his faith and constant belief and devotion to G-d while demonstrating immense humility even while serving as a minister. The "beloved" is seemingly a fitting accolade to signify that his behavior is worthy of imitation.

Answer (score 3):

A guess:

In Ch. 10 verse 3 Daniel says  לֶחֶם **חֲמֻדוֹת** לֹא אָכַלְתִּי - that during the 3 years he fasted, he didn't eat *clean bread*.

He refers to this bread as לֶחֶם חֲמֻדוֹת

Maybe that's why he was then referred to as the אִישׁ **חֲמֻדוֹת** - the beloved man (your translation) or the pure man (Rashi's translation) or the man of exalted character (Metzudoth's translation).

As in: You gave up your לֶחֶם חֲמֻדוֹת so you deserve to be called an אִישׁ חֲמֻדוֹת.

Comment: +1 Your guess is most probably right as so many people are referred to places that they were or events that happened in their time E.g Shmuel Haramasi (place),Morrdechai Bilshan(spoke 70 languages)

Comment: This is made explicit in Yoma 76b, see the parenthesis

Comment: Thanks, @rikitikitembo - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.76b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en for those who want to see it inside.

Comment: note though that Daniel is referred to as beloved in chapter 9 (possibly chronologically before his fast in chapter 10)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rav Matis Weinberg](https://www.thelivingtree.org/nach-yomi/?book=7) (chapter 9, starting at around 1:10) this label is related to Daniel's concept of self-identity and is the inverse of לֹא תַחְמֹד not to covet (Shemot 20:14) and is applied to Daniel because of his connection to prayer which is something that is desired by God